# GEE, function, max Y values for each X

Tags: google-earth-engine, function, scatterplot

I would like to create a function to plot just the higher y values for each x.

For example:

```
var x = ee.List([01,01,01,03,04,05,05,09,10,10,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,17,20])

var y = ee.List([19,19,18,16,16,15,14,13,13,10,09,08,07,07,07,06,05,04,03,02])
```

After removing the repeated pairs:

- also remove (01;18) and leave (01;19),
- remove (05;14) and leave (05;15),
- remove (10;10)/(10;09) and leave (10;13),
- remove (17;03) and leave (17,04)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below is a little awkward but I believe this is the best way to do it. You convert your values to a feature collection because these are easier to filter and manipulate in general, that way you can separate each distinct x value along with its corresponding y values in order to calculate the max.

```
var x = ee.List([1,1,1,3,4,5,5,9,10,10,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,17,20])
var xDistinct = x.distinct()
var y = ee.List([19,19,18,16,16,15,14,13,13,10,9,8,7,7,7,6,5,4,3,2])

var indexes = ee.List.sequence(0,y.length().subtract(1));
var xyFeatCol = ee.FeatureCollection(indexes.map(function(index){
  var xVal= x.get(index)
  var yVal = y.get(index)
  return ee.Feature(null,{x:xVal,y:yVal})
}));

var yValuesMax = xDistinct.map(function(xVal){
  var yValues = xyFeatCol.filter(ee.Filter.eq('x',xVal))
  var yValueMax = yValues.aggregate_max('y')
  return yValueMax
})
print(xDistinct)
print(yValuesMax)
```

Comment: you made it!!!!! i dont have words to thank u!!!!!! thanks thanks thanks